# How to effectively use Path.Combine with starting backslash in string?

Tags: c#, path

I am using C# Path.Combine method to combine paths as below

```
string str1 = "C:";                   // This value can be read from configuration
string str2 = "\Dataaccess\bin";      // This value can be read from configuration
string combinedPath = Path.Combine(str1,str2);
```

My expectation is combinedPath should return "C:\Dataaccess\bin"
But it returns \Dataaccess\bin

If I change the str1 value to "C:" like below,

```
string str1 = "C:\";                   // This value can be read from configuration
string str2 = "\Dataaccess\bin";      // This value can be read from configuration
string combinedPath = Path.Combine(str1,str2);
```

Then also it returns \Dataaccess\bin

If I change the str1 value to "C:" and then str2 value to "Dataaccess\bin" like below,

```
string str1 = "C:\";                   // This value can be read from configuration
string str2 = "Dataaccess\bin";      // This value can be read from configuration
string combinedPath = Path.Combine(str1,str2);
```

Then only it's returning correct value "C:\Dataaccess\bin"

How to get the expected result "C:\Dataaccess\bin" with inputs "C:" and "\Dataaccess\bin" because these 2 values are retrived from configuration file which cannot be changed.

Comment: You could trim the strings: `str2.Trim('\\');`

Answer (score 5):

I think the easiest is to remove the `\` at the beginning of `str2`:

```
str2 = str2.TrimStart('\\');
string combinedPath = Path.Combine(str1, str2);
```

For the why it behaves like that: it is documented in [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-7.0):

> If the one of the subsequent paths is an absolute path, then the
> combine operation resets starting with that absolute path, **discarding
> all previous combined paths**.

The second string `str2` is an UNC path, so an absolute path, because it is [rooted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.ispathrooted?view=net-7.0).

The .NET source:

```
private static string CombineInternal(string first, string second)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(first))
        return second;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(second))
        return first;

    if (IsPathRooted(second.AsSpan()))
        return second;

    return JoinInternal(first.AsSpan(), second.AsSpan());
}
```